# Keep row selected in QTableView

Tags: qt, qt4

I am working on a program to view and edit records in a file.  It features a `QTableView` that displays all records, a `QLineEdit` to search for records, and some labels that display the details of the selected record:

[image: record viewer]

There is a `QAbstractTableModel` class that holds the data and a `QSortFilterProxyModel` class that helps filtering the rows in the `QTableView`.

Searching and filtering works fine.  Typing text in the search box immediately filters the list of records.  But there are two things I cannot get to work:

1. if the list is not empty, I want one item to be selected/current always
2. the selected/current item must be brought into view when typing in the search box

For example, when I type "tesla", the list will be empty since no item matches.  But as soon as I backspace to "te", the "Forester" matches and I want it to be selected.  Second example: when (after starting the program) I type "f" the list is narrowed down to 8 items and "Pacifica" is selected.  When I erase the "f", the Pacifica is still selected but no longer in the visible part of the list.

I have posted the full source code of this on [Pastie](http://pastie.org/10910508), and here are some (hopefully) relevant snippets.

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEditSearch_textChanged(const QString & text)
{
    itemProxy->setFilterFixedString(text);

    updateStatusBar();
}

void MainWindow::currentRowChangedSlot(QModelIndex const & current, QModelIndex const & /*previous*/)
{
    Car * car = 0;

    if (current.isValid())
    {
        QModelIndex sibling = current.sibling(current.row(), COLUMN_THIS);
        QVariant variant = itemProxy->data(sibling);
        car = static_cast<Car *> (variant.value<void *> ());
    }

    updateCarMake(car);
    updateCarModel(car);
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget * parent, CarItemModel * itemModel, CarSortFilterProxyModel * itemProxy) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    this->itemModel = itemModel;
    this->itemProxy = itemProxy;

    ui->setupUi(this);
    setupStatusBar();

    ui->tableView->setModel(itemProxy);

    ui->tableView->setColumnHidden(COLUMN_THIS, true);

    QItemSelectionModel * selectionModel = ui->tableView->selectionModel();

    connect(selectionModel, SIGNAL(currentRowChanged(QModelIndex const &, QModelIndex const &)),
            this, SLOT(currentRowChangedSlot(QModelIndex const &, QModelIndex const &)));

    connect(selectionModel, SIGNAL(selectionChanged(QItemSelection const &, QItemSelection const &)),
            this, SLOT(selectionChangedSlot(QItemSelection const &, QItemSelection const &)));

    ui->tableView->selectRow(0);

    ui->lineEditSearch->setFocus();

    updateStatusBar();
}

<widget class="QTableView" name="tableView">
 <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
  <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn</enum>
 </property>
 <property name="selectionMode">
  <enum>QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection</enum>
 </property>
 <property name="selectionBehavior">
  <enum>QAbstractItemView::SelectRows</enum>
 </property>
</widget>
```

So, my question is: how can I make sure an item is always selected and in the visible part of the list (unless the user is scrolling, of course)?

Comment: Well, I figured this out.  I need to get back to work, but I'll post the answer to both questions shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did to

- always have an item selected, and
- have the selected item visible when searching

The solution is even a bit fancier since when going from no visible items to some visible items the most recently selected item will be selected instead of just the first item.

First, I added a `QModelIndex lastModelIndex;` private member to the `MainWindow` class, and set it in the `SelectionChanged` slot.  Note that the model index is stored and not the proxy index.

```
void MainWindow::selectionChangedSlot(QItemSelection const & selected, QItemSelection const & /*deselected*/)
{
    if (selected.count() > 0)
    {
        QModelIndex index = selected.indexes().first();
        QModelIndex modelIndex = itemProxy->mapToSource(index);

        lastModelIndex = modelIndex;
    }
}
```

Next, I added two methods: `ensureSelected()` ...

```
void MainWindow::ensureSelected(QItemSelectionModel * selectionModel, int const proxyCount)
{
    if (selectionModel->hasSelection())
    {
        // an item is currently selected - don't have to do anything
    }
    else if (proxyCount == 1)
    {
        // no item is currently selected, but there is exactly one item in the list - select it
        QModelIndex proxyIndex = itemProxy->index(0, 0);

        selectionModel->setCurrentIndex(proxyIndex, QItemSelectionModel::Select | QItemSelectionModel::Rows);
    }
    else if (proxyCount > 1)
    {
        // no item is currently selected, but there are several items in the list

        QModelIndex proxyIndex; // !isValid

        if (lastModelIndex.isValid())
        {
            // there's a most recently selected item - compute its index in the list
            proxyIndex = itemProxy->mapFromSource(lastModelIndex);
        }

        if (proxyIndex.isValid())
        {
            // the most recently selected item is in the list - select it
            proxyIndex =  proxyIndex.sibling(proxyIndex.row(), COLUMN_THIS);
        }
        else
        {
            // there's no most recently selected item or it is no longer in the list - select the first item
            proxyIndex = itemProxy->index(0, 0);
        }

        selectionModel->setCurrentIndex(proxyIndex, QItemSelectionModel::Select | QItemSelectionModel::Rows);
    }
    else
    {
        // There are no items in the list - cannot select anything.
    }
}
```

... and `ensureVisible()`:

```
void MainWindow::ensureVisible(QItemSelectionModel * selectionModel)
{
    if (selectionModel->hasSelection())
    {
        const QModelIndex index = ui->tableView->currentIndex();

        ui->tableView->scrollTo(index);
        ui->tableView->selectRow(index.row());
        ui->tableView->scrollTo(index);
    }
}
```

Weird as it may seem, I have to call `scrollTo()` twice, or the tableView won't scroll.

These new methods are called from `on_lineEditSearch_textChanged()` like so:

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEditSearch_textChanged(const QString & text)
{
    itemProxy->setFilterFixedString(text);

    QItemSelectionModel * selectionModel = ui->tableView->selectionModel();

    int modelCount = itemModel->rowCount(); // number of items in the model
    int proxyCount = itemProxy->rowCount(); // number of items in tableview

    ensureSelected(selectionModel, proxyCount);

    ensureVisible(selectionModel);

    updateStatusBar();
}
```

Please find the updated and complete source code on [Pastie](http://pastie.org/10914082).

Comment: Thanks, the 2 scrollTo calls solved my problem.  Could you explain WHY scrollTo() needs to be called twice?  It works, but I can't explain why.

Answer (score 0):

Handle selection change signal and connect it to your custom slot:

```
 QSortFilterProxyModel *model = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
    connect(ui->tableView->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(selectionChanged(QItemSelection,QItemSelection)), this, SLOT(selectionChanged(QItemSelection,QItemSelection)));
```

Every time, you table change the current selection the app should select the first item in the model:

```
void MainWindow::selectionChanged(QItemSelection selected, QItemSelection deselected) {
    // Use this 
    const int rows = ui->tableView->selectionModel()->selectedRows().size();
    // or 
    const int rowCount = selected.size();

    // Lets select the first item if there are some items availables
    if (rowCount < 1) {
        const int availableItems  = ui->tableView->model()->rowCount();
        if (availableItems > 0) {
            const QModelIndex index = ui->tableView->model()->index(0,0);
            ui->tableView->selectionModel()->select(index, QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect);
        }
    }

}
```

By this way, you should have at least one item selected.

Comment: Tried this, but it doesn't work, alas.  When I search for cars matching "fa" (there are none), `selectionChanged` tries to select the first of the eight cars matching "f".  So it looks like the `tableView->model()` (which is the `QSortFilterProxyModel`) is not updated yet when `selectionChanged` is invoked.
Also, it does not keep the current/selected item in view (as seen when typing "f" and then Backspace).

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was way easier to just set selection-background-color QWidget styleSheet property in the ui settings to any color you desire.

That's it!